# Republic of Ireland country boundary shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, data, ireland

Does anyone know where I can get shapefiles for the country border of the Republic of Ireland?

Ideally I would like these to be in British National Grid (BNG) projection, as I have to show these on a map which includes Northern Ireland, England, Scotland and Wales.

Comment: You can download Ireland shapefiles from [DIVA-GIS](http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata) by selecting `Ireland` as Country and `Administrative areas` as _Subject_. These come in a .zip file which when extracted, will give you shapefiles of two levels. For boundaries, you can use "IRL_adm0.shp". **Note that the projection for these shapefiles are in EPSG:4326 so you will need to reproject them using a conversion or GIS software**.

Comment: I'd get them from gadm: http://www.gadm.org/country - I don't know how often the DIVA-GIS data are updated, but there's no South Sudan. GADM does have South Sudan. Not that it's part of Ireland, but anyway...

Comment: DIVA-GIS data saus its GADM version 1.0 - GADM is now up to version 2.8, so I'd say use that for admin boundaries.

Comment: You can also find a copy here http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=ae74a8497a1041669a9d2165a0f450b6  has a copy of the admin boundaries of Ireland and N. Ireland.  You will have to reproject using GIS software.

Answer (score 4):

Here you can download the Republic of Ireland boundaries: http://census.cso.ie/censusasp/saps/boundaries/ED_SA%20Disclaimer1.htm

I don't think they're in BNG projection, but you might convert it I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if this is what you are looking for

http://www.gadm.org/country